# How to display the current recent rows according to time?

Tags: mysql, linux

---

The following database generated by (select * from users).How can i display the recent rows according to time(i.e for time i had used date +%s).But here it displays all timing .I nee dthe rows with the recent update time.

```
| time       | userid   | groupid   | 
+------------+----------+-----------+
| 1477044791 | spolishe | MEMS      |         
| 1477044791 | ssarkar  | HCG       |        
| 1477044791 | svaranas | PDSP_DES  |       
| 1476868065 | dnehra   | HCG       |       
| 1476868065 | dprabhu  | PDSP_DES  |
```

My expected Output:(but it sould be generated by using some linux commands like date +%s).Is there any linux commands which fetches the only the last recent time rows (or) Is it possible to use inside insert mysql query by storing in some variable name.

```
| time       | userid   | groupid   |

| 1477044791 | spolishe | MEMS      |         
| 1477044791 | ssarkar  | HCG       |        
| 1477044791 | svaranas | PDSP_DES  |
```

Comment: You can create a script that sends a query to the database, the query should use UNIX_TIMESTAMP();

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to represent the time in proper date formant? if so;

```
select from_unixtime(time), * from user order by time desc
```

Comment: If you want to filter the dataset you can use select * from user where time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(<date>)

Answer (score 0):

You could specify that you only want items where the time is equal to that of the largest value that column holds in the table.

`SELECT * FROM users where time = (Select max(time) from users);`